# How to sum up all rows based on a enumeration column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, sum, max

))Hi all, this is my table...

[image]

I would like to create a trigger function that whenever 'Total' is INSERTed on the timetype column it would SUM up all timeelapse FROM mytable WHERE fnname = 'ff' AND timetype = 'Lap' but only where timeindex has the highest decimal value (eg. in mytable = 1.1, 2.3, 3.3) (let's say the max possible decimal value its 1.9 or 2.9 or 3.9 and son on). So in the table above the trigger function would automatically sum up all blue highlighted squeares and place it in the last timeelpase row (where timetype = 'Total'). I How can I do that?

Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your data by the integer part of timeindex:

```
select distinct on (floor(timeindex)::int) 
    floor(timeindex)::int idx, timeindex, timeelapse
from mytable
where fnname = 'ff'
and timetype = 'Lap'
order by 1, 2 desc;

 idx | timeindex | timeelapse 
-----+-----------+------------
   1 |       1.1 | 01:00:00
   2 |       2.3 | 03:00:00
   3 |       3.3 | 08:00:00
(3 rows)
```

In the trigger calculate the sum from the above query:

```
select sum(timeelapse) from (
    select distinct on (floor(timeindex)::int) 
        floor(timeindex)::int idx, timeindex, timeelapse
    from mytable
    where fnname = 'ff'
    and timetype = 'Lap'
    order by 1, 2 desc
    ) alias;

   sum    
----------
 12:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi klin, thanks for reply, I have try your code but when trying to create the function I get this ERROR message: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "DESC" ..WHERE fnname = 'ff' AND timetype = 'Lap' ORDER BY 1, 2, DESC` am I missing something? What does `idx` mean in this part of your code `floor(timeindex)::int idx, timeindex, timeelapse` isn't that `idx` out of place?? btw I made a mistake in some detail, the count should be 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04 instead of 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, so it can keep counting like 1.09, 1.1, 1.11, 1.12, it is the same right? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Remove comma after 2 in `ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC`.

Comment: idx is an alias for a column - it is in place. (it is just like `floor(timeindex)::int as idx,...`)

Comment: Of course, it is ok with1.01, 1.02, etc. as we are getting integer from the number.

Comment: Hi Klin, the code worked after removing the comma, but I have some doubts... I know the DISTINCT ON keeps only the first row of each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal and the FROM ensures that the desired row appears first. But I don't understand why you put an alias `idx` there, is it the same `alias` that appear at the end of the code? what does `alias` mean? How can I fill the NEW.timeelapse column with the sum result? To do so I usually do `SELECT SUM(timeelpase) FROM (your code) INTO sumvariable` and then `NEW.timeelpase = sumvariable` Does `idx` replace this step?

Comment: pls Klin I just wanted to know where are `idx` and `alias` been used? what is its purpose? why are they there for? Thanks advanced.

Comment: `idx` is just a name of the first column of the query. In your trigger it is unnecessary and you might remove it at all. `alias` is necessary (a subquery in a `from clause` must have an alias), even though it is not used anywhere else.

Comment: sorry last one doubt, why `1, 2` in `ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC` what does that `1, 2` exactly mean? Thanks man

Comment: This is an abbreviation for `ORDER BY floor(timeindex)::int, timeindex DESC` (1, 2 are numbers of column).

Comment: Hi @klin I raised up some subquestion from this function of yours, please hope you could give a hand with that since you are already related with the issue, Thanks Advanced. the linnk is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145580/how-to-sum-up-all-rows-based-on-a-enumeration-column-in-postgresql-part2