# How to tweak the SET intervalstyle (change the Interval Output) in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, intervals

I have read in this online PostgreSQL documentation... http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-datetime.html#INTERVAL-STYLE-OUTPUT-TABLE
in the point 8.5.5 something about how to tweak the default Interval Output. . I mean the default interval is shown like this...

```
00:00:00.000 (if the timedifference is lower than a day or month or year)

1 day 00:00:00.000 (if the timedifference reaches days, but is lower than a month or a year)

1 month 1 day 00:00:00.000 (if the timediffence reaches months, but is lower than a year)

1 year 1 month 1 day 00:00:00.000 (if it reaches years, months, days)

it evens uses plurarl cases (years, mons, days) when their values are greater than one.
```

All these variations make difficult to any other app when SELECTing (query) this interval values (as text) to convert it to a proper time. So I would like postgresql to always show year, month n days, even if their value are 0 (it could be even better if it could show the date part of the interval like this... 01-11-30, adding zeros to the left side when values are less than ten)

I know I can change the interval to text, using to_char() but I really would like to avoid that, I would like some good fellow postgresql programmer to tell me if it is true that there is a way to tweak the Interval Output as is said in the postgresql documentation.

Thanks Advanced.

PD: two more links about the subject
https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Statements/SET/SETDATESTYLE.htm
http://my.vertica.com/docs/6.1.x/HTML/index.htm#13874.htm

Comment: I think you already mentioned how you should do it - use `to_char`, or write a (pretty simple) parser for the interval format. I don't think there's any supported way to modify the interval output, and the output must always be readable by the interval *input* function in PostgreSQL so a generic format expression couldn't be implemented even if you wanted one.

Comment: Why those links (included postgresql documentation) talk about an "Set Interval output"?? Any hint? Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the interval output style, but only to one of a few pre-defined formats that are unambigious on input, and that PostgreSQL knows how to parse back into intervals. Per [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#INTERVAL-STYLE-OUTPUT-TABLE) these are the SQL standard interval format, two variants of PostgreSQL specific syntax, and iso_8601 intervals.

If you want something familiar and easy to parse, consider using:

```
SET intervalstyle = 'iso_8601'
```

and using an off-the-shelf parser for ISO1601 intervals.

Comment: Hi Craig, when should I put `SET intervalstyle = 'siso_8601'` in the table's properties (next to interval column type)?? inside the function that autofill the interval column?? what do you mean by... _using an off-the-shelf parser for ISO 1601 intervals?_ Thanks Advanced

Comment: You don't. It's a session property. You can `ALTER USER ... SET` or `ALTER DATABASE ... SET` if you want to make it persistent for a particular user or particular database.

Comment: As for the second part: don't write your own code to read the ISO 1601 interval format. Use a library.